# hive query compare substr vs LIKE to string that ends with exact substring

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

i want to filter string_field that ends with "_ends_with" from a very large table on Hive 2, i have 2 choices, the EXPLAIN of both of them looks pretty much the same one using substr and the other using LIKE , what is better in performance wise ? what will run faster over time / use less resources ? thire EXPLAIN reutrn the exact same result other than predicate section , i will want to use this logic later with join with other big tables.

### query 1 using substr

```
SELECT id, url
FROM table
WHERE order = 0
  ... -- some more AND filter 
  AND substr(string_field, -9) = "_end_with";
```

VS

### query 2 using LIKE :

```
SELECT id, url
FROM table
WHERE order = 0
  ... -- some more AND filter 
  AND string_field LIKE "%\_end_with";
```

Comment: I guess the difference will be minor, and it's not worth optimizing these thing imho

Comment: Why you do not consider RLIKE also : `string_field RLIKE ".+_end_with$"` And for sure you will never notice the difference in performance, it is executed in parallel on many mappers. Use partitioning to improve performance

Answer (score 0):

For this type of question, you would need to test which performs better on your data in your environment.

Second, the two are *not* equivalent, because `_` is a wildcard in `LIKE` expressions.  So, the `LIKE` would match `!end!with` for example.

I will add, though, that I would expect them to have similar performance.  Both have to read all the data in the table and run a string comparison of some sort.  Reading the data is typically the most expensive part of a query like this.

There might be some additional overhead to `LIKE`, particularly because it is dealing with three wildcards rather than just one.  But remember that `LIKE` is a built-in operator and there have been decades of effort to make it efficient in SQL engines.

Personally, I would use `LIKE` regardless of any small performance concerns.  I have spent time debugging queries where I changed the pattern I'm looking for -- and miscounted the characters.  Mistakes in queries are much worse for performance whatever difference might exist between your two methods.